# Mapbox filters based on array

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have the following array:

```
test = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I would like to filter objects on the map if they exist in the array.
Is it possible to use this filter with array:

```
mapObj.setFilter("hover", ['all', ["in", "letter", test[0]]]);
```

Or alternately, what is the best way to filter object that exist in the array?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well mapbox's setFilter function does not accept an array as a parameter. You will need to use a format that fits their API which is basically described here under "Set Membership Filters".

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#filter

To filter multiple variables the Set Membership Filters require a specific format which is

`["in", key, v0, ..., vn]`

Where v0 to vn are elements of your array which yields

`["in", "letter", "a", "b", "c"]`

One could write a function to convert an array to this format. Maybe like this:

```js
function buildFilter(arr) {
  var filter = ['in', 'letter'];

  if (arr.length === 0) {
     return filter;
  }
  
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    filter.push(arr[i]);
  }
  
  return filter;
}

var filterBy = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var myFilter = buildFilter(filterBy);

console.log(myFilter);

// then you would use it like this:
// mapObj.setFilter("hover", buildFilter(['a', 'b', 'c']));
```

Answer (score 5):

`["in", "letter", ...test]` in ES6

should work.

Comment: It's an elegant way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
['in', 'letter'].concat(test);
```

Where `test` is your array of values.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a native way of doing this, as shown in the ["Filter features within mapview" example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-features-within-map-view/).

You will have to use a unique attribute of your elements (ideally a unique ID). In your case, given that the attribute is "letter", the code would be the following:

```
mapObj.setFilter('hover', ['match', ['get', 'letter'], test, true, false])
```

For a better understanding of the code, take a look at the [documentation about the match expression](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-match).

Answer (score 0):

I used it with .map like in [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-features-within-map-view/). I think you should avoid an extra method for concatenation.

> ```
>          this.$store.map.setFilter(layerName, [
>           'match',
>           ['get', filterPropertyName],
>           currentValues.map((feature) => {
>             return feature;
>           }),
>           true,
>           false
>         ])
> ```